# error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments

Tags: c++

I have voting method in cpp file like below method:

```
void CMOReplicationlayer::Voting(std::list<CMOData*>* pa_repQueue, CMOData* pa_votedData)
    { 
        pa_repQueue->sort(&CMOReplicationlayer::compare_d);
        pa_votedData = pa_repQueue->front();
    }
```

and I have `CMOData struct` in header file like this:

```
struct CMOData
        {
            TForteByte* pa_pvData = NULL;//Received data serialization byte
            unsigned int pa_unSize = 0;//The size after adding Date & Time
            CIEC_TIME* pa_Offset = NULL;//Offset Value
            TForteUInt64 pa_recvDateTime = NULL;

            bool operator()(CMOData first, CMOData second)
            {
                bool result = false;
                if (first.pa_recvDateTime == second.pa_recvDateTime)
                    result = true;
                return result;
            }
        };
```

and `compare method` like this:

```
bool compare_a(const CMOReplicationlayer::CMOData& first, const CMOReplicationlayer::CMOData& second)
        {
            return first.pa_recvDateTime < second.pa_recvDateTime;
        }

        bool compare_d(const CMOReplicationlayer::CMOData& first, const CMOReplicationlayer::CMOData& second)
        {
            return first.pa_recvDateTime > second.pa_recvDateTime;
        }
```

But I don`t know why I get this error when I want to use`Sort` method of list in cpp file.

```
"error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments"
```

Comment: sort is using `less`, unless you are sending your own comparison functor. send in `compare_d` as a third parameter, or overload < to use it

Comment: Shouln't `pa_repQueue->sort(&CMOReplicationlayer::compare_d);` be `pa_repQueue->sort(CMOReplicationlayer::compare_d);`?

Comment: your list contains pointers, your comparing function expects references. also, is `compare_d` a non-member function or at least a static one?

Comment: Please remember to format your question so we can understand things like that jumble of code-like characters just before the end. Or delete the duplicated text.